# Gallery image must open up in fancybox directly not post page

Tags: gallery

I am inserting a number of galleries onto a page using the multiple galleries plugin. I want the image to open up in fancybox (highslide js variant or some such) when clicked and installed another plugin called easy fancybox.

The problem I am facing is that when the image is clicked in the gallery the image opens up its own post page and when that image is clicked it opens up in a fancybox. I want it to open up directly in a fancybox.

I would also like the fullsize image to open up in a fancybox not just the thumbnail.

I am quite sure this is possible and I am just doing something silly.

Thanks in advance.

Nandakumar Chandrasekhar

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any good lightbox-like option that works in WP 3.2.1?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34082/any-good-lightbox-like-option-that-works-in-wp-3-2-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your galleries are set as Links to *"Image File"* and not to *"Attachment Post"* for Galleries and images. You'll find the settings in the image/galleries pop-up window.

I'm not familiar with your plug-in but you might need to manually add the fancybox class to each image. Another option is to add the code to your theme manually and skip the plug-in. I've posted an answer here: [Any good lightbox-like option that works?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34082/any-good-lightbox-like-option-that-works-in-wp-3-2-1/34119#34119).

Comment: Thanks for that. I found this out after some time but could not post here due to my reputation. Thanks once again.